# Xamarin.Forms.Maps をインストールするとパッケージ android.support.v7.internal.widgetは存在しませんというエラーが出る

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-maps, xamarin

## 環境

- Windows10
- Visual Studio 2015
- Visual Studioにインストールされている Xamarin のバージョン 4.1.1.3
- プロジェクトにインストールされた Xamarin.Forms / Xamarin.Forms.Maps バージョン 2.3.0.107
- Samsung Galaxy Note Edge(Android 5.0)(ビルドできてないのであまり関係なさそう）

## 質問

Xamarin.Forms PortableアプリにXamarin.Forms.MapsのNugetパッケージをインストールしてビルドするとエラーが出ます。

### パッケージがないと言われるエラー

> エラー        繧ｨ繝ｩ繝ｼ: 繝代ャ繧ｱ繝ｼ繧ｸandroid.support.v7.internal.widget縺ｯ蟄伜惠縺励∪縺帙ｓ
>       private native void n_onInflate (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewStubCompat p0, android.view.View p1);
>   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar(com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.class): 隴ｦ蜻・ 繧ｿ繧､繝・RequiresPermission'蜀・↓豕ｨ驥医Γ繧ｽ繝・ラ'anyOf()'縺瑚ｦ九▽縺九ｊ縺ｾ縺帙ｓ: android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission縺ｮ繧ｯ繝ｩ繧ｹ繝ｻ繝輔ぃ繧､繝ｫ縺瑚ｦ九▽縺九ｊ縺ｾ縺帙ｓ
>   豕ｨ諢・荳驛ｨ縺ｮ蜈･蜉帙ヵ繧｡繧､繝ｫ縺ｯ髱樊耳螂ｨ縺ｮAPI繧剃ｽｿ逕ｨ縺ｾ縺溘・繧ｪ繝ｼ繝舌・繝ｩ繧､繝峨＠縺ｦ縺・∪縺吶・
>   豕ｨ諢・隧ｳ邏ｰ縺ｯ縲・Xlint:deprecation繧ｪ繝励す繝ｧ繝ｳ繧呈欠螳壹＠縺ｦ蜀阪さ繝ｳ繝代う繝ｫ縺励※縺上□縺輔＞縲・
>   豕ｨ諢・蜈･蜉帙ヵ繧｡繧､繝ｫ縺ｮ謫堺ｽ懊・縺・■縲∵悴繝√ぉ繝・け縺ｾ縺溘・螳牙・縺ｧ縺ｯ縺ｪ縺・ｂ縺ｮ縺後≠繧翫∪縺吶・
>   豕ｨ諢・隧ｳ邏ｰ縺ｯ縲・Xlint:unchecked繧ｪ繝励す繝ｧ繝ｳ繧呈欠螳壹＠縺ｦ蜀阪さ繝ｳ繝代う繝ｫ縺励※縺上□縺輔＞縲・
>   繧ｨ繝ｩ繝ｼ7蛟・
>   隴ｦ蜻・蛟・  HogeApp.Droid   C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HogeApp\HogeApp\HogeApp.Droid\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v7\internal\widget\ViewStubCompat_OnInflateListenerImplementor.java    33

というようなエラーが7つ出ます。どうすれば解決できるでしょうか。
おそらくJavaコードに関連するエラーなのですが、文字化けしています。
文字化けを変換して推測される内容は、

> エラー: パッケージandroid.support.v7.internal.widgetは存在しません 
>   private native void n_onInflate (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewStubCompat p0, android.view.View p1); C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar(com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.class): 警呁E タイチERequiresPermission&039;冁E��注釈メソチE��&039;anyOf()&039;が見つかりません: android.support.annotation.RequiresPermissionのクラス・ファイルが見つかりません 注愁E��?部の入力ファイルは非推奨のAPIを使用またはオーバーライドしています
>   詳細は、EXlint:deprecationオプションを指定して再コンパイルしてください、ファイルの操作��EぁE��、未チェチE��また��E安��EではなぁE��のがあります�?�E 
>   詳細は、EXlint:uncheckedオプションを指定して再コンパイルしてください

です。

どうもJavaコードに問題があるように見えます。
しかしコードは初期状態からいじっていません。（Mapsインストール前に実行した時はちゃんとハローワールドが動作しました。）

また、[Xamarin逆引きTips Xamarin.Formsで地図を表示するには？](http://www.buildinsider.net/mobile/xamarintips/0039)の記事のようにパーミッションの設定やAPIキーの記述などを行ってみても同様のエラーが出ます。

### 参照コンポーネントが見つからないという警告

> 参照コンポーネント○○が見つかりませんでした。

という警告も11個出ます。
見つからないコンポーネントは

- Bing Maps for C#,C++,or VisualBasic
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows
- System.ObjectModel
- Xamarin.Forms.Core
- Xamarin.Forms.Maps
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Tablet
- Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

です。
Nugetパッケージの復元やVSの再起動をしても同様に出ます。こちらも初期状態のハローワールドでは出現していませんでした。Mapsをインストールすると出ます。

---

調べようにも文字化けしていてなかなか参考になる記事が見つかりません。
解決に向けて皆様にお力添えいただければうれしいです。

---

追記
皆様回答ありがとうございます。いろいろ試したのですが、上手くいかなかったので何かの機会にすべてインストールし直そうかと思っています。
また、同様の症状の方も居ないようなので、単純に自分の導入ミスのような気がします。

Answer (score 2):

以下のような環境で、Xamarin.Forms.Maps の nuget パッケージは問題なく使えています。

#### 試したサンプルプログラム:

- [Map Control - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/)

からダウンロードできる MapsSample サンプル

#### Visual Studio, Xamarin 等のバージョン:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA282
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA282
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA282
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   5.209.60613.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.20512.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v2.9.1   14.0.20519.0
Azure App Service Tools v2.9.1

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.6000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Common Azure Tools   1.7
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0
A Visual Studio Extension that brings the GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 1)   14.1.20512.0
Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 1)

Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service   2.0.6000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.6000.0
An integrated development environment for HDInsight application development.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.9.40518.2

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60311.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript   1.8.31.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.25219.00
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a single universal app experience that can reach every device running Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

Xamarin   4.1.0.530 (2e39740)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   6.1.0.71 (4e27558)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   9.8.0.323 (39ebb77)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.
```

#### Androidプロジェクトの `packages.config` ファイルの内容：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.0.107" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
<package id="Xamarin.Forms.Maps" version="2.3.0.107" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
<package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="29.0.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid50" />
</packages>
```

#### インストールされている Android SDK:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記以外の項目が Installed になっていないか、特に Android N、 API, Rev が 24 のものがインストールされていると正しく動作しないので、その場合はアンインストールしてみてください。

特に、Android SDK, `packages.config` が異なるのではないかと思います。
確認してみてください。

文字化けについてですが、私は [Windows 10 の開発環境](https://developer.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/downloads/virtual-machines) に Xamarin をインストールして仮想環境で使っています。こちらは言語設定が英語なので、エラーなどは文字化けせず全て英語で出力されます。ご参考まで。

Answer (score 0):

参照コンポーネント～の部分に関してですが、
Windowsプロジェクトの設定に関するエラーだと思われます。

必要ないならプロジェクトを削除、
必要ならば、WindowsプロジェクトにNugetの
Xamarin.Forms,Xamarin.Forms.Windows,Xamarin.Forms.mapが追加されているか確認してください。
BingMaps～は、WindowsのSDKの設定も必要になるかと思います。